# How do I use Bazaar with a HTTP proxy?

Tags: bazaar, http-proxy

How do I use Bazaar with a HTTP proxy? I can't find anything in their documentation.

Comment: I'm curious, in what context are you using Bazaar? Is it your decision or a previous programmer's decision? Was there a reason it was used over git and svn? Thanks!

Comment: Personally, I prefer Mercurial or SVN. The reason for trying to get bzr working is to download code from Launchpad. Problem is getting it to work over the company proxy...I've always had good success using hg or svn.

Comment: bzr++. There's enough git fanboys in the world already!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set the `http_proxy` environment variable to point to your proxy, eg. (on Windows):

```
set http_proxy=http://webcache.mycompany.com:3128/
```

See the "Environment variables" section of http://bazaar-vcs.org/ConfiguringBzr

Comment: Currently, we have a project hosted over launchpad and our network is behind a proxy which does not allow us to send data over SSH. I'm currently using Windows XP and have set the http_proxy variable. Since it doesn't work, I'm assuming that regardless of having set the proxy variable, the restriction of the proxy to SSH is causing the problem. Will it solve the problem then if I request SSH be allowed by our network administrator? Or can I resolve this problem without having to ask changes in our network settings?

Thanks!

Comment: @Paul: Do you really mean SSH?  Or SSL?  If you're using HTTP, you're not using SSH.  You're using SSL if your URLs start with 'https', and your proxy will need to allow SSL (aka TLS).  But I don't know anything about Launchpad - does it require SSL?  Can you simply remove the 's' from 'https'?  If you really do mean SSH, I don't think your proxy is relevant - instead, you need to configure your firewall to allow outgoing SSH.

Comment: @RichieHindle: launchpad seems to require SSH to send account details and allow you to access/modify files in the server. In this case you're right, it is probably not the proxy causing the problem but the firewall. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Also do not forget to set `HTTPS_PROXY` environment variable.

```
set https_proxy=http://my.proxy.com:3128/
```

Answer (score 0):

I post this answer as a reference for those who may later visit this page.

If you still have trouble with proxy connection after trying all the other methods, try setting your proxy settings using dconf and gconf editors.

### Note:

The settings that the latest programs are expected to use are the DConf settings but some old programs might still use GConf settings, so it is wise to set your proxy settings in both.

If not already installed, you can easily install dconf and gconf editors from synaptic or the package manager of your distribution.

### Proxy Settings:

In your Conf dconf editor traverse to

`system > proxy`

There you should see the options for setting your ftp, http, https, socks proxy settings.

### Note:

In case your proxy needs authentication, and your password contains special characters like`@` you would know by now (after painstaking searches), that you should replace your `@` with %40 (the HTML character encoding for `@`) while configuring your proxy settings, eg. in ~/.bashrc.

Do not follow this practice in the configuration editor. Type your password as it is.

Now, in case of gconf editor, the path to the proxy settings is same, but the options might be a bit different. But, I am sure you can make it out.